# How can I change a labels text on a certain time

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications

The label must change when the page loads. I don't get any errors but the label stays what I named the label.

my code:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DateTime curTime = DateTime.Now;

    int one = 5; //times of day
    int two = 12;
    int three = 20;

    string ogg = "Oggend";
    string mid = "Middag";
    string aan = "Aand";

    if (curTime.Hour >= one && curTime.Hour <= two)
    {
        timelbl.Text = ogg;
    }
    else if (curTime.Hour > two && curTime.Hour < three)
    {
        timelbl.Text = mid;
    }
    else
    {
        timelbl.Text = aan;
    }

}
```

I tried to put `timelbl.Text = "Oggend"` in aswell but it didn't work.
Oggend means Morning, Middag means Day and aand means Night

Comment: Make sure your code is being executed. Debug. Check your @page declaration on your .aspx and make sure its wired to the correct codebehind and inherits your class.

Comment: Thanks it was with the code behind where the problem was.

Answer (score 0):

Using variables for "times of day" is redundant. You may keep them if that's what you want, but it won't be the best thing to do.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) { 
    DateTime curTime = DateTime.Now;

    int one = 5; //times of day
    int two = 12;
    int three = 8;

    string ogg = "Oggend";
    string mid = "Middag";
    string aan = "Aand";

    if (curTime.Hour >= one && curTime.Hour <= two)
    {
        timelbl.Text = ogg;
    }
    else if (curTime.Hour > two && curTime.Hour < three)
    {
        timelbl.Text = mid;
    }
    else
    {
        timelbl.Text = aan;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be fine. You just need to make sure that page load event fires so that the variable value assigned to the label. You should add a break point in page load event and ensure that the event fires properly.